# how do i use async>httpGet(port,url

Tags: lua

in im rather new to lua so thats why i ask these question
how do i make  a toggle to press where if i press it it only regesters the press for one tick but not for everything the button is ouputing to only one thing like once it adds one to the number it stops adding instead of going to 100 or infinite

```
base = 1
num = 1
rectX = 1
rectY = 1
rectW = 10
rectH = 10
function onTick()
isPressed = input.getBool(1)
inputX = input.getNumber(3)
inputY = input.getNumber(4)
output.setBool(1, isPressingRectangle)
if inputX >= rectX and inputY >= rectY and inputX <= rectX+rectW and inputY <= rectY+rectH
then inRectangle = true 
    else inRectangle = false 
end
if isPressed and inRectangle then isPressingRectangle = true 
    else isPressingRectangle = false 
end
if isPressingRectangle then num = (num + 1) 
    if num > base + 1 then num = (num - 1)
        elseif num < base then num = (num + 1)
end
function onDraw()
if (isPressingRectangle) then screen.setColor(0,255,0) screen.drawRectF(rectX,rectY,rectW,rectH)
    else
        screen.setColor(255,0,0) screen.drawRect(rectX,rectY,rectW,rectH)
end
screen.drawText(16,16,inputX)
screen.drawText(35,16,inputY)
screen.drawText(54,16,num)

end
end
end
```

I have a different problem but stackoverflow wont let me ask it so ill ask it in the comments because i cant get a clear answer or i couldnt find one

i have treid a until but it crashes and i dont know how to make it be a toggl button either withour memory reg

Comment: the title is explainitory

Comment: Hey @Rhys Smith, it's really hard reading this to figure out what's going on. Can you please try and edit your question to be very specific and clear about what the problem is, and what you're expecting?